# ios9 swift2 ekeventviewcontroller done bar button disappear

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ekeventkit

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let eventVC = EKEventViewController()
        eventVC.event = eventItems[indexPath.row]
        eventVC.allowsEditing = true
        eventVC.allowsCalendarPreview = true
        eventVC.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(eventVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Bar button disappeared.....

Help me

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let eventVC = EKEventViewController()
    eventVC.event = eventItems[indexPath.row]
    eventVC.allowsEditing = true
    eventVC.allowsCalendarPreview = true
    eventVC.delegate = self

    let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: eventVC)
    nav.modalPresentationStyle = .PageSheet
    self.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Finally solve the problem

Comment: You cannot initialize the navigation controller with EKEventViewController, it just crashes. EKEventViewController opens the native Calendar app which cannot function inside your app.